# reading output of command or read from a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I'm new to bash and want to improve. I need to learn reading specific text from a file or from output of a command.For example I want to sum of the total ethernet interrupt numbers of each core of the computer from /proc/interrupts file.The content of the file is:

```
CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
0:        142          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
1:          1          0          1          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
4:        694         18        635         19   IO-APIC-edge      serial
7:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      parport0
9:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
12:          1          1          0          2   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
14:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      ide0
19:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3
23:          0          0          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1,  uhci_hcd:usb2
46:     347470     119806     340499     108227   PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
47:      33568      45958      46028      49191   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-rx-0
48:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-tx-0
49:          1          0          1          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
50:      28217      42237      65203      39086   PCI-MSI-edge      eth1-rx-0
51:          0          0          0          0   PCI-MSI-edge      eth1-tx-0
52:          0          1          0          1   PCI-MSI-edge      eth1
59:     114991     338765      77952     134850   PCI-MSI-edge      eth4-rx-0
60:     429029     315813     710091      26714   PCI-MSI-edge      eth4-tx-0
61:          5          2          1          5   PCI-MSI-edge      eth4
62:    1647083     208840    1164288     933967   PCI-MSI-edge      eth5-rx-0
63:     673787    1542662     195326    1329903   PCI-MSI-edge      eth5-tx-0
64:          5          6          7          4   PCI-MSI-edge      eth5
```

I need to read all of the numbers of interrupts with "eth" keyword and then find the sum of them for each CPU core(whateve the CPU core name is). For example for CPU0:33568+0+1+28217...
What is suitable for this? Must I use awk or sed for regex and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk` for this, there is *no* need for grep or any other tool since awk can do the search itself.

**UPDATE**:

Based on the possibility of varying number of CPU columns (see first comment below), this will work:

```
NR==1 {
  core_count = NF
  print "core count: ", core_count
  next
}
/eth/ {
  for (i = 2; i <= 2+core_count; i++)
    totals[i-2] += $i
}

END {
  print "Totals"
  for (i = 0; i < core_count; i++)
    printf("CPU%d: %d\n", i, totals[i])
}
```

gives output:

```
core count:  4
Totals
CPU0:  2926686
CPU1:  2494284
CPU2:  2258897
CPU3:  2513721
```

*Notes*:

If the first line only contains CPU headers, then using `NF` as shown at the start of the script will work. If other data might be present then `core_count = gsub(/CPU/, "CPU")` could be used. Also, this script depends on consecutive CPU columns.

Comment: that is a good answer but CPU0 is static.What if I dont know the name and number of the CPU cores.For example if it starts with cPU1 and goes through CPU9.Must I read the core names before and assign to variables for this script or is there a way to read in this script

Comment: @barp give this a try, preferably with different number of CPU columns and let me know if this works for you. I'm using arrays here, just fyi. Also note, I am printing out the number of cores found in the 3rd line of the script, you can just delete that if it's not needed (thought it might be helpful for debugging).

Comment: From presented structure of the report the NR would be enough to detect number of CPU's I guess.

Comment: @nshy Excellent point .. I guess I could change this and put a note about it requiring no other data. Thanks for pointing out this simplification.

Comment: @Levon Also it would be much simpler loop if you iterated from 0 to core_count and set totals[i] += $(i+2)

Comment: @nshy Either will work, I like mine better in a way since it makes it *explicit* that I start looking for CPU data in field 2. (both constructs look a bit "hack'ish" due to the addition/subtraction :)

Comment: Thanks a lot it is useful.A last question, what if the columns are not consecutive?

Comment: @barp Is that a possibility? I wouldn't think so from the format you presented. I would complicate the script since now it starts collecting CPU counts in field 2 and looks at consecutive fields (determined by core_count).

Comment: @barp If that happens (non-consecutive columns) it would be best to post a *new* question with that problem. This question already changed once from fixed 4 columns/CPUs to flexible number, so you don't want to stray too much from the original post or keep evolving/changing the problem.

Comment: @barp Happy I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out the eth lines using `grep`, and then [sum using awk](http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/linux_ls_awk_totals.php).

e.g. for CPUs 1 and 2:

```
grep eth report | awk '{ CPU0 += $2; CPU1 += $3} END { print CPU0; print CPU1} '
```

Note that you can [filter within awk](http://gilmation.com/articles/filtering-lines-in-awk/), rather than use `grep` for this.

I would perhaps be tempted to do this in Perl however, and create a hash of sum per CPU. It would depend on how extensible I want to make this.

Comment: that is a good answer but CPU0 is static.What if I dont know the name and number of the CPU cores.For example if it starts with cPU1 and goes through CPU9.Must I read the core names before and assign to variables for this script or is there a way to read in this script